# Combining two lists by summing elements with same indexes does not work

Tags: prolog

Second day I am trying to make something like this work:

```
?- sm([1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6], X).
X = [4,6,8,10].
```

I have something like this for now:

```
sm([], []).
sm([Head1|Rest1], [Head2|Rest2], R) :- 
    ResultElem is Head1 + Head2, 
    append([ResultElem], R, R1), 
    sm(Rest1, Rest2, R1).
```

I get only:

```
Singleton variables: [X]
false
```

Why does it not working and how this can finally be overcome?

Comment: Student of WMI says: thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Wish you good luck on a Saturday's exam ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your recursive `sm/3` does not have a matching base, because you wrote `sm/2` by mistake:

```
sm([], [], []). /* You forgot the third pair of [] brackets */
```

As far as the recursive clause goes, it is easier to put the result in the header of the rule, and it lets you avoid using `append`:

```
sm([Head1|Rest1], [Head2|Rest2], [ResultElem|R]) :-
    ResultElem is Head1 + Head2,
    sm(Rest1, Rest2, R).
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use maplist :

```
add(X,Y,Z) :-
    Z is X+Y.

my_sum(L1, L2, L) :-
    maplist(add, L1,L2,L).
```

With SWI-Prolog and module lambda, you can write

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

my_sum(L1,L2,L) :-
    maplist(\X^Y^Z^(Z is X+Y), L1, L2, L).
```

Finally, with module clpfd, you can have:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

my_sum(L1,L2,L) :-
    maplist(\X^Y^Z^(Z #= X+Y), L1, L2, L).
```

and we have :

```
 ?- my_sum([1,A, 9] ,[B,5,6], [5,7,C]).
A = 2,
B = 4,
C = 15.
```

Comment: (there's also `plus/3`...)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was sure there was something. I looked in General purpose arithmetic, not in Special purpose ... !